# Drawing graphics2D java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, lines

I need to draw a circle between 2 lines. When I click on the panel, a line is drawn. When I click a second time, another line is drawn and the color of the line has changed. Also, at the 2nd click, a circle is drawn between the 2 lines. Then, there is a little animation with the circle. Someone helped me yesterday with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26950769/230513) :

```
List<Integer> yClicks = new ArrayList<>(); {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  
            yClicks.add(e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    for(int y : yClicks) {
        g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, y, getWidth(), y));
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

I added this:

```
for(int y : yClicks) {

    line1= new Line2D.Double(0, y, getWidth(), y);
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2d.draw(line1);


    int l2= (yClicks.get(1));

    int Diameter=l2-y;
        g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2d.draw(new                Line2D.Double(0,l2,getWidth(),l2));
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(getWidth()/2,(Diameter),10,10));
}
g2d.dispose();
}
```

But there is a problem withe the code and maybe circle are drawn. I never used this form of a for loop, so i don't know. how to add something on the loop. I also tried `if(y==2)` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: _"i never used this form of a for loop so i don't know"_ - For each integer value in `yClicks`, give it the variable `y`. You need to decide what to do with `y` (the integer value)

Comment: It can easily be change to `for (int i = 0; i < yClicks.size(); i++) { int y = yClicks.get(i); }` if that helps you understand it better